# Best Way To Locate Offending WP Table

Tags: export, wp-list-table

I am trying to import a production db into local test db.

**Problem**
I can't locate and therefore can not exclude a table from the `wp db export eclude_tables=....` command, which contains a path that only exists on the production server because the paths to wordpress between test and production change base on username, in this case `admin` vs. `adminOther`

this is the specific error, that I get when trying to import the production db:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Warning: require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Warning: require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Warning: require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Warning: require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Warning: require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Warning: require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(913): WSAL_SensorManager->__construct()
#1 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/wp-security-audit-log.php(367): WpSecurityAuditLog->init()
#2 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WpSecurityAuditLog->setup()
#3 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-settings.php(461): do_action()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1317): require('...')
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1235): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(28): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(78): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process()
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('...')
#12 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('...')
#13 {main}
  thrown in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
Warning: require_once(/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php on line 69
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-activity-log-for-woocommerce/wp-security-audit-log/custom-sensors/WSAL_Sensors_WooCommerce.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/adminOther/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/classes/SensorManager.php:69
```

**Question(s):**
1.) Is there a straightforward to locate the name of the db table contains the offending path?

2.) Is there a `wp db ...` command or some other method to quickly determine which db tables belong to which plugins?   A plugin *registry table* of some kind perhaps?

In the current situation, I excluding the following tables:

```
--exclude_tables=wp_users,wp_usermeta,wp_actionscheduler_actions,wp_actionscheduler_claims,wp_actionscheduler_groups,wp_actionscheduler_logs,wp_itsec_bans,wp_itsec_dashboard_events,wp_itsec_distributed_storage,wp_itsec_fingerprints,wp_itsec_geolocation_cache,wp_itsec_lockouts,wp_itsec_logs,wp_itsec_mutexes,wp_itsec_opaque_tokens,wp_itsec_temp,wp_itsec_user_groups,wp_litespeed_avatar,wp_litespeed_url,wp_litespeed_url_file
```

I previously believed that these tables belonged to the XXX plugin, but that doesn't seem to be the case:
`wp_actionscheduler_actions,wp_actionscheduler_claims,wp_actionscheduler_groups,wp_actionscheduler_logs`

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual to include/require files based on database values, but if that's what's happening — one way to track it down would be to export the DB from production to an SQL file (which maybe you already have), then search through it with a text editor. You should then be able to look at the INSERT statement (I think it is) and see what table it is being added to.

If I may suggest — rather than exclude tables, you may want to run a command after import to the local site that searches and replaces the old string in all the tables. At a previous employer, we used [Search Replace DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) to get the job done. It took a while, but worked very well.

Comment: I agree with you.  I -should- be able to export the db without excluding anything , then search-replace, the db to replace the username / update path.  However, I am encountering the error above, during the db import, causing db import to fail before my script can run search-replace.  Excluding certain tables helps, but shouldn't be necessary.  Perhaps I need to ask  different question?   

Comment: Ah, because the error is already present on the local site, the WP CLI won't work. What if you deactivated that plugin that is causing the error (WP Security Audit Log) and then ran the `wp` command?

Comment: `because the error is already present on the local site` the value of experience... you are absolutely correct... I literally just figured that out... a previous bad import into the local site left a bad path value.  I just corrected it...  The core problem seems to be that my wp import command actually causes the problem.    the local site has username "adminabc" the stanging site has username "adminabcs" , so search-replace is creating an invalid path  at 'adminabcss' <-- How can I prevent this?

Comment: Note: I already have double quotes on all variables and values

Comment: I fixed the username problem... the issue above seems to be unique to only the audit log family of plugins...  I just lost 2 days troubleshooting my bash script, when the actual plugin is broken... Imagine how angry I am right now.   Warning to anyone using their plugin.. you literally have to deactivate the plugin, then export your db or you get impossible errors